# Mostrar una vista de una consulta innerjoin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Quiero mostrar una vista de un inner join pero se me complica. OJO: es una relación de muchos a muchos.

```
public function show(Chica$chica)
    $manillas = Chica::with('manillas')->get();
    $relacion = DB::table('chicas')
    ->join('manillas','chicas.id','=','manillas.id')
    
    ->get();
    return view('chicas.show',data:compact('chica'));
```

Probé con esto pero me dice que las variables no están definidas.

Vista desde el blade.php

```
@foreach($manillas as $manilla)
  @foreach($manillas->chicas as $chica)
    <tr>
      <li>{{$chica->nombre_chica}}</li>
      <li>{{$chica->edad}}</li>
      <li>{{$manilla->id}}</li>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: debes agregar tu query y en modo texto no imagen...

Comment: buenas tardes, para comprende mejor el problema y dar una respuesta es necesario que publique la consulta o la función del a consulta

Comment: Hola. En tu modelo tienes definido la relación con "chicas"?

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Además, ¿cómo depurarías el código de una imagen? Piénsalo.

Comment: Para la proxima intenta colocar el codigo y no imagenes, segundo es complicado porque hay muchos puntos que estan mal, primero, debes pasar a la vista las variables que quieres acceder desde ella, aqui solo estas pasando chica pero no pasas manillas (el compact).

Comment: no debería ser $this->manillas ?

Answer (score 0):

En tu problema dice que es un modelo de mucho a mucho
por el cual el modelo seria asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el controlador esta seria la consulta

```
public function index(){

    $dato = chica::with('manilla_all.manilla_id_pk')->get();
    return View::make('Reporte.pdf_no_conformidad',compact('dato');
}
```

**//Modelo de App/ChicaModel.php**

```
<?php
    
    namespace App; 
    class ChicaModel extends Model 
    {
      protected $table = 'chica';
    
      public function manilla_all(){
          return $this->HasMany(chicaHasManilla::class, 'chicaId');
      }
        
    }
?>
```

**//Modelo de App/chicaHasManillaModel.php**

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App; 
    class chicaHasManillaModel extends Model 
    {
      protected $table = 'chica_has_manilla';
    
      public function manilla_id_pk(){
          return $this->belongsTo(ManillaModel::class, 'manillaId');
      }
        
    }
?>
```

modelo de manilla

```
<?php
    
    namespace App; 
    class ManillaModel extends Model 
    {
      protected $table = 'manilla';
      /*
      public function manilla_id_pk(){
          return $this->belongsTo(ManillaModel::class, 'manillaId');
      }
      */
        
    }
?>
```

y en la vista seria el foreach

```
 @foreach ($dato as $chica )
    @foreach ($chica['manilla_all'] as $manillaAll )
        {{$manillaAll['manilla_id_pk']['nombre']}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```